# How to set local namespace for specified connection?

Tags: python, namespaces

I want to write a simple python C/S exec code model, which will send all codes written in client to execute in server.

Simply, you can think that I'm using `exec(code, globals())` to run remote code.

And I meet a problem about namespace :

If I import something in a connection, another connection can also use this module.

For example, we have two connections: A and B.

I `import os` in connection A, then connection B can use `os` module also.

Question : And what I want is that each connection have its own execute environment, say `'globals'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I'm using a stupid and violent solution.

I create dict for each connection,  and exec code in dict accordingly.

`exec code in connection_dict[connection]`.

Any smart solution ? Such as python CAPI ? Thanks again!